# Setting mouse position

Tags: glut

Is there a function in glut which moves the mouse to a specific position?
There is a similar function in SDL (SDL_WarpMouse) but I want to stick to glut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just found it, you just have to ask the right question and google helps :D

Its `glutWarpPointer(middleX, middleY)`;

Answer (score 1):

Unless you also hide the pointer this will be very ugly.  I used this once for a class project and it did the trick but it looked horrible.  but then again I was using it to emulate purely relative mouse movements (basically so it couldn't leave the window).  But other than that, yeah, it does the job.